# Model is not able to over-fit even a single audio file after 200 epochs

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, speech-recognition, recurrent-neural-network

batch_size=1

NUM_HIDDEN=80

NUM_LAYERS=4

learning_rate=0.001

NUM_EPOCH=200

```
max_placeholder=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)
input_tensor=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.float32,shape=[None,None,40])
input_tensor_4d=tf.reshape(input_tensor,shape=[-1,max_placeholder,40,1])

sequence_length=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.int32,shape=[None])

training_placeholder=tf.placeholder(dtype=tf.bool)

label_placeholder=tf.sparse_placeholder(dtype=tf.int32)

conv1=tf.layers.conv2d(input_tensor_4d,filters=64,kernel_size=[3,3],strides=(1,1),padding='same',name='conv1',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.variance_scaling())
batch_norm1=tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv1,training=training_placeholder,name='batch_norm1')
conv1_activation=tf.nn.relu(batch_norm1,name='conv1_activation')
conv1_max_pool=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv1_activation,padding='same',pool_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),name='conv1_max_pool')

conv2=tf.layers.conv2d(conv1_max_pool,filters=32,kernel_size=[3,3],strides=(1,1),padding='same',name='conv2',kernel_initializer=tf.initializers.variance_scaling())
batch_norm2=tf.layers.batch_normalization(conv2,training=training_placeholder,name='batch_norm2')
conv2_activation=tf.nn.relu(batch_norm2,name='conv2_activation')
conv2_max_pool=tf.layers.max_pooling2d(conv2_activation,padding='same',pool_size=(2,2),strides=(1,1),name='conv2_max_pool')

rnn_input=tf.reshape(conv2_max_pool,shape=[-1,max_placeholder,40*32])
cell_fw=[tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(NUM_HIDDEN, state_is_tuple=True,initializer=tf.initializers.variance_scaling()) for _ in range(NUM_LAYERS)]
cell_bw=[tf.contrib.rnn.LSTMCell(NUM_HIDDEN, state_is_tuple=True,initializer=tf.initializers.variance_scaling()) for _ in range(NUM_LAYERS)]
rnn_output,_,_=tf.contrib.rnn.stack_bidirectional_dynamic_rnn(cell_fw,cell_bw,rnn_input,sequence_length=sequence_length,dtype=tf.float32)

fully_connected=tf.contrib.layers.fully_connected(rnn_output,28,activation_fn=tf.nn.relu)
fully_connected_transpose = tf.transpose(fully_connected, (1, 0, 2))

loss=tf.nn.ctc_loss(label_placeholder,fully_connected_transpose,sequence_length,time_major=True)
cost=tf.reduce_mean(loss)

with tf.control_dependencies(tf.get_collection(tf.GraphKeys.UPDATE_OPS)):
    optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(cost)

decoded, neg_sum_logits = tf.nn.ctc_greedy_decoder(fully_connected_transpose,sequence_length)

label_error_rate = tf.reduce_mean(tf.edit_distance(tf.cast(decoded[0], tf.int32),label_placeholder))
```

**i have written this tensorflow model for speech recognition system and to check whether model is correct or not, I tried to overfit it on a single audio file of just 2 seconds(over 200 epochs), but it still doesn't recognize the speech of that single audio perfectly.
Now, I am not encountering any error as such but just want to cross check if my model is ready or has some pretty obvious mistakes.
I have used 2 layers of CNN, followed by 4 bi-directional RNN layers, and finally 1 fully-connected layer. CTC loss function with ADAM optimizer.
Can anyone please have a look at my code and specify any striking mistake.
Thank You**

Comment: Do formatting of the question, also write the error you get. Describe what the code does.

Comment: Please, format all the code. Also, try tu put less code, most of the question is code. Describe better the problem and the question.

Comment: Updated question. Please check it.